# Jquery change form action based on body class

Tags: jquery, forms

I'm trying to set up my form so that the action will change based on the body class.

Form setup -

```
<form action="basicURL" method="post" id="quoteForm">
```

Jquery setup -

```
if ($('body').hasClass('hosting')) {
$('#quoteForm').attr('action', 'hostingURL');
}
```

Everything I've seen seems to indicate it should be working, but it's not.

Comment: Depends on when or where your code is executed. I.e. has the document finished loaded.

Answer (score 1):

Your code does work.

You need to wrap your JQuery in a ready function to make sure it loads at after your page is drawn.

```
$('document').ready(function () {
    if ($('body').hasClass('hosting')) {
        $('#quoteForm').attr('action', 'hostingURL');
    }
});
```

Here is a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/27sAD/)

Comment: That isn't working either. I noticed a little typo in function, but I fixed that and still no luck.

Comment: @MollyCampbell Yeah, To make sure I fixed all the typos I created a working fiddle and copied over.  If you run the fiddle then inspect the submit button you can see the form action is changed.

Comment: Okay, I see. Thank you. I was viewing the page source on my site and the action URL didn't change - but it is changed if I inspect the button. Any idea why that would be?

Comment: Best guess would be check the id names match including case, the id names are case sensitive, and just to be sure you do have jquery linked on your page?

Comment: If you view source, you’re only seeing what the server sent, not what might have been dynamically updated or added by any scripts that ran after page load. Inspecting reflects the current state of the DOM.

Comment: Perfect, thanks. One last question - how do I expand this to include more body classes? This is what I have right now

Comment: $('document').ready(function () {
    if ($('body').hasClass('hosting')) {
    $('#quoteForm').attr('action', 'hostingURL');
    }
    elseif ($('body').hasClass('workspace')) {
    $('#quoteForm').attr('action', 'workspaceURL');
    }
    else{}
});

Comment: You should probably post new question for that